# TypeLoadException in C# form app with IKVM

Tags: c#, java, ikvm

I have written a simple java class file i.e

```
package Test;
public class Message {
      public static String getMessage(String msg)
      {
          return "Hello "+msg;
      }
}
```

converted this .jar file to .dll using ikvmc then Referenced this "IkvmTest.dll" and IKVM.OpenJDK.Core in my C# form app which is like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = Test.Message.getMessage("MyName");
}
```

But it is giving me error after clicking button as
`"Could not load type 'Test.Message' from assembly 'IkvmTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"Test.Message"`

and interesting thing is that it worked perfectly in C# console app where java class file is

```
package Test;
public class Message {
      public static void getMessage(String msg)
      {
          System.out.println("Hello "+msg);
      }
}
```

Please help regarding form application.
**Update:** My problem is solved now. Actually the project name of java(IkvmTest.jar) and C# forms app(IkvmTest) was same hence name of generated .dll(IkvmTest.dll) from jar and C# app was conflicting. So just creating C# project with different name solved my problem.

Comment: After 8 questions, you still don't know how to format your question?

Comment: @L.B Actually when I typed the question preview was not available and after editing and proper formatting it I just got error that Roman Vottner edited your post! Sorry and thank you.